# Javascript : Replacing the blank spaces of a specific keyword in the textarea

Tags: javascript, input, replace, textarea, keyword

I need your helpful for writing a javascript function to replace a specific words with other words in a textarea.

I want find and replace in textarea the blank spaces among the word(s) placed on input text:

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Replace Specific words in textarea</title>
</head>
<body>
<Form name="frm" method="post" id="frm">
<TextArea name="txtArea1" cols="85" rows="10" ID="Textarea1">
While it was clear that forwarding the material was naughty (and the "culprits" had their wrists smacked), there.
This is one of the#main#ways of using link events. If you have not seen rollover images before, they are images 
</TextArea><br>
Input keywords: <Input type="text" name="findwords" value="the main ways" id="text1">
<Input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Bob

Comment: Be more precise on what you want. What has to be the result after replacing?

Comment: Replace the blank spaces of the input keywords found in the textarea with "#" - just the blank spaces of the keywords: For example: input text:"the main ways"  <TextArea >
While it was clear that forwarding the material was naughty (and the "culprits" had their wrists smacked), there.
This is one of **the#main#ways** of using link events. If you have not seen rollover images before, they are images 
</TextArea><br>

Comment: Taking into account the instances of that keywords inside textarea...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to really understand, but try this :

```
// Execute instructions when the button with ID "submit" is clicked.
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function()
{
    // Get user inputs.
    var search = document.getElementById('text1').value;
    // Replace spaces and tabs with a regular expression.
    var alteredSearch = search.replace(/\s/g, '#');
    // Get the textarea content.
    var look = document.getElementById('Textarea1').value;

    // Finally, replace the textarea content.
    document.getElementById('Textarea1').value = look.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), alteredSearch);
});
```

I see you have a form. Currently, if you hit the submit button, your page will reload, and nothing will be done. Set the **type** attribute of your input to `button` if you want your javascript to work.

Comment: Ok. I set the input button to  "button", but when I place your JS code inside <script> and in head, but the first line does an error message: It is null or it is not an object.

Comment: Put your <script> at the end of your <body>

Comment: Sorry, not works.  http://www.phrasenet.com/webapp/replacetextarea.html

Comment: Of course it didn't work, you also removed the **id** attribute of your input. **type** is "button", **id** is "submit".

Comment: ooops! It dos works fine on my desktop computer, but not in my smartphone and tablet (as well as other files executing javascript). Do uou know why and how fix it?

Comment: Your javascript may be turned off on your devices. Try searching in your browser settings?

Comment: Thank you. You are right. The issue are dealing with uppercase when input data on the <input type=text>. I can fix it using the keyword upcase option in my tablet/smartphone or coding a little script in JS.